# Combine separate page with default culture

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

Is there any way I can combine separate page with default culture, means when I change to the other language than the US I will see the same not translated page.
I can do that for the whole site using the 'Combine with default culture' setting from the Multilingual content settings, but that is not what I need, as far as some pages should not be displayed for other languages than the US.

I am using the Kentico 11 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that is you don't want to use the "Combine with default culture" setting:

- While switching to other language choose copy content from default language, but you have then duplicated content so you need to edit it twice when needed
- Specify the english version to have culture unique url/path (for example by configuring it in Properties -> Urls -> Path or pattern property) and then setup redirection on that other language page to redirect there (Properties -> Navigation -> URL redirection)

Comment: in case I specify English version and then redirect other languages to it the language selected will be changed as well(

Comment: That is true, the culture changes with the page.